# Exporting pwcorr matrix from Stata to LaTeX

Tags: stata, stata-macros, readstata13

I want to export the correlation matrix of variables var1 to var6 in Stata to a LaTeX table. Specifically, I want to display var1 to var3 in the row and var2 to var6 in the column. i.e. the pairwise correlation table (with standard errors in parentheses) would look like this:

```
       var1 var2 var3
var2    #
var3    #    #    
var4    #    #    #
var5    #    #    #
var6    #    #    #
```

However, I am having trouble with both exporting pwcorr outcomes to LaTeX and selecting the variables which I want to display in rows and columns.

Comment: "having trouble" could mean (1) I have no code (2) I have code but it's not doing what I want (3) I have code but I get error messages -- and more beyond. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the standard here of a reproducible example with data and code. I suspect that you may need to wrote your own code: this is not necessarily available as canned code.